# Remove linebreaks from print_r output

Tags: php, arrays, logging, replace, line-breaks

I have the following PHP code:

```
$array = array('huey' => 'red', 'dewey' => 'blue', 'louie' => 'green', 'webby' => 'pink');
$postDataForLog = print_r($array, true);
$postDataForLog = str_replace('\n', ' | ', $postDataForLog);
log($postDataForLog);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is simple. Write the content of the array into a logging file. To keep the file organised, I need to keep each logging message on one line. So I want to reduce the output of `print_r` to one line and replace line breaks with `|`. However, this doesn't work for some reason and while I want the output in the file to be like this:

```
Array | ( | [huey] => red | [dewey] => blue | [louie] => green | [webby] => pink | )
```

it is like this:

```
Array
(
    [huey] => red
    [dewey] => blue
    [louie] => green
    [webby] => pink
)
```

Comment: Using single quotes means `'\n'` is `\n`, more flexible would be to replace `'\n'` with `PHP_EOL`.  You could also just output it using `json_encode()`.

Comment: Damn, such a beginner mistake. Thanks a lot, this works.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$array = array('huey' => 'red', 'dewey' => 'blue', 'louie' => 'green', 'webby' => 'pink');
$postDataForLog = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $postDataForLog[] = "[$key] => $value";
}
echo ('Array | ( | '.implode(' | ', $postDataForLog).' | )');
//Output: Array | ( | [huey] => red | [dewey] => blue | [louie] => green | [webby] => pink | )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?

$array = array('huey' => 'red', 'dewey' => 'blue', 'louie' => 'green', 'webby' => 'pink');

$postDataForLog = implode(" | ", $array);

echo $postDataForLog;

?>
```

Comment: Today is apparently not my day... How could I not think about this?! Thank you, this works.

Comment: This unexplained answer, of course, omits the keys -- clearly not what the question calls for.